# Two Date objects are the same but comparing them still returns false

Tags: javascript

Can anybody explain why the following code outputs `false`?

```
alert(new Date(2014, 8, 8) == new Date(2014, 8, 8));
```

Tested with Chrome and Firefox. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DHilgarth/dn6p8kgm/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparisons between objects in JavaScript are always simple reference comparisons. Two object references are the same only if they refer to the exact same object.

You can compare dates by making them numeric:

```
alert(+(new Date(2014, 8, 8)) == +(new Date(2014, 8, 8)));
```

The `+` unary operator will force the Date instances to be converted to numbers by calling the `.valueOf()` method on each. The Date `.valueOf()` returns the same thing as `.getTime()`, that being the underlying timestamp.

Comment: Ah, because a `Date` isn't a built in type like a string?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth it is a built-in type, but it's an *Object* type. Strings and numbers and booleans are called "primitive" types.